# Ways to get AuditTrail data in Django

Tags: python, django, audit-trail

I'd like to know what's the best way to get data from AuditTrail table in views.
I'd like to show all the versions of a model's fields using a template and a view. I looked for a way to show it in admin area but I had no success.

Answer (score 1):

look at Django reversion https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion

It should do what you need.

Comment: I've already tried to use it, but I could use just the option to recovery deleted rows. How do I use the option of showing a history?

Comment: @LeandroAbilio, I'm also looking to do exactly that, showing a history of changes for a given model object for audit purposes. I don't know if you're aware that the django-reversion package has a few helpers to show differences between versions? Also, this package (an extension for reversion) gives a few further options, but it is built to be used in the admin: https://github.com/jedie/django-reversion-compare